# Get an image without seeing it first

Tags: python, simplecv

I am currently working with SimpleCV for some image processing. Basically my goal is to have my application take a picture from a simple command in Python, i.e. 'GetPicture()'.
In SimpleCV, it is very easy to get an image from the camera, by using

```
cam = Camera()
img = cam.getImage()
```

My problem is that the first line actually shows the camera stream on the screen, and this I don't want. I would like to be able to get the image while displaying something else on the screen, thus taking the picture in 'blind mode'. Possible ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Julien

Answer (score 0):

For those interested...

Eventually I used Pygame in combination with v4l (video for linux) driver. The v4l driver has a `no-preview` option, which once set, enables one to take a picture in 'blind' mode.

Julien